# Turn off memory dump on BSOD in XP

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I know I've seen this option before, but I can't find it for the life of me.  Straight and simple:

**Where can I find the option to disable the memory dump that occurs during a BSOD in Windows XP?**

I recall seeing options for the memory that is dumped during the BSOD being something along the lines of:

- Full
- Minimal
- Disabled

*I understand its purpose, but I've never used it. At least knowing where the option is means I can always turn it on later if I have a BSOD that I actually want to debug.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `System Properties` (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>Pause / Break</kbd>).

Open the `Advanced` Tab and click on `Settings` under `Startup and Recovery`.

Should be there!

[image]